# OTB planning for apparel category

Tags: optimization

I have been allocated the OTB (open to Buy) budget at the start of the month for purchasing products in apparel category for online retail.

The inventory purchased on the budget should serve the following  objective:

1. Meet the demand forecast for the month
2. Ensure a certain target sell through of the inventory
3. Minimize the chance of mark downs of the inventory

Problem statement :

1. How do I allocate the budget across brands to buy products (both old and new season)?

Example output: Allocate $10k for brand A, buy 10 styles each with quantity 20 units for new season merchandise, where as buy 15 styles with 30 units for old season merchandise. Please note that I can't allocate all the budget to the best brand. It would result in lower variety available to the customers that would lead to sales loss.

This has similarities to the merchandising planning problem. I have the forecast at overall level, not at style or brand level. I also have historical purchase, product attributes , margins, customer browse and transaction data. Is there any analytical framework to solve this problem ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.